# Reference explaining the history and motivation behind Heyting algebra?

Tags: reference-request, logic

I'm starting to have an interest in Heyting Algebras and their application in topological spaces. Is there any paper/reference which gives a history based exposition of it's ideas?

Comment: [Moschovakis, The Logic of Brouwer and Heyting](https://ucirvine.instructure.com/courses/3605/files/1250392/download?verifier=8kARyqwjq6i3m1vskfCsPLYljwAGMcvrclgyEjT7)